# prestashop - catch when a product is added to cart

Tags: php, e-commerce, prestashop-1.6

- We implemented a new module for prestashop, where you can add
  products for persons. A user can place an order for 1..n persons. To
  difference products, we added a person_id column on cart_product
  table.

The problem appeared when we tried to use price_rules, and specific when we tried to give one gift for each person because the rules are applied only one time per cart, but we want to apply one time per person.

1. Is there a way to add multiple gifts per cart?
2. How can I catch the exact moment when a product is added to cart by the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you need to check hook `CartAction`. It will call when some one add product to the cart.